# Access Select statements

Tags: sql

Following is the statement that I am trying to use.

I have two tables (deposits and company) I am trying to get the (account balance) from the deposits table so I can put it into the (Accounts Balance) in the company table. When I run the code I watch the (Account Balance) in the deposits table. Watch tell me that SSQL is 'out of context' and deposits.[Account Balance] 'Expression not defined in context'.

```
Dim SSQL As String
SSQL = "SELECT deposits.[Account Balance] FROM deposits WHERE deposits.[Bank Name] = company.[Bank Name]"
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to join the two tables like this:

```
SELECT deposits.[Account Balance] 
FROM deposits
INNER JOIN company
ON deposits.[Bank Name] = company.[Bank Name]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the more than one table in one sql statement then you need to join the tables..........

by using

[INNER JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208854%28v=office.12%29.aspx),[LEFT JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208894%28v=office.12%29.aspx),[RIGHT JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208894%28v=office.12%29.aspx)